# Typescript - Extend object with generic key

Tags: typescript

I would like a method that takes an object and adds a property to it, such as this one:

```js
const augment = <T extends {}, K extends string>(obj: T, key: K): T & { [x in K]: string } => {
    return { ...obj, [key]: "someString" };
};
```

This fails with

```js
Type 'T & { [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T & { [x in K]: string; }'.
```

I understand that `key` is does not retain the `keyof K` aspect.
In an idal world, if I call

```js
const anObj = { aProp: 'aVal' };
const anotherObj = augment( anObj, "aKey" );
```

I would like the signature of `anotherObj` to be `{ aProp: 'aVal', aKey: string }`. In particular when the key argument is a literal.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: How much do you care about TypeScript's type safety enforcement inside the implementation of `augment()`?  If you're happy with the call signature, then leave it alone and use an assertion inside the implementation like (for example) [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkjr0m).  Note that if `key` is of a union type you get bad return types; instead you might want [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8LAN), and if you really want to see expanded properties instead of `&` you might want [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5J6W).  If you want to see any of that expanded into an answer, let me know.